# Getting line equation from Segmented Package Function in R Language

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

```
 X=c(-    0.000000446,0.000006498,0.00001344,0.00002039,0.00002733,0.00003427,0.00004122,0.00004816,0.00005511,0.00006205,0.000069,0.0000836,0.00009821,0.0001128,0.0001274,0.000142,0.0001566,0.0001713,0.0001859,0.0002005,0.0002151,0.0002297,0.0002443,0.0002589,0.0002735,0.0002881,0.0003027,0.0003173,0.000332,0.0003466,0.0003612,0.0003758,0.0003904,0.000405,0.0004196,0.0004342,0.0004488,0.0004634,0.000478,0.0004926,0.0005073,0.0005219,0.0005365,0.0005511,0.0005657,0.0005803,0.0005949,0.0006095,0.0006241,0.0006387,0.0006533,0.000668,0.0006826,0.0006972,0.0007118,0.0007264,0.000741,0.0007556,0.0007664)
 Y=c(0,61820,73630,83830,93720,103600,109000,112700,116100,119500,120900,122100,123300,124300,125300,126600,127800,129000,130100,131200,132300,133300,134200,135200,136100,136900,137800,138600,139400,140100,140900,141500,142200,142800,143500,144000,144600,145100,145600,146100,146600,147000,147400,147800,148200,148500,148800,149100,149300,149600,149800,149800,149900,149800,149700,149300,148500,148000,147600)
 plot(X,Y)
 linear1=lm(Y~X)
 linear2=segmented(linear1,seg.Z=~X, psi = 0.0005,data=d)
 plot(linear2)
 points(X,Y)
 slope(linear2)
```

What i am trying to do is to get a bilinear representation of the curve given here. First of all i wanna ask if there is any better way than my code? Second and important thing is that i dont know what function or command displays the intersection point of the lines and the equations of each lines. So the question is how to get the line equations out of this segmented command.

Answer (score 3):

is is not clear what do you mean by `bilinear` representation of the curve. To get lines equations, you can should use `intercept` and `slope` like this:

```
intercept(linear2)
$X
             Est.
intercept1  22730
intercept2 119200

> slope(linear2)
$X
            Est.   St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
slope1 2.938e+09 288100000   10.20 2.360e+09 3.515e+09
slope2 4.872e+07   3840000   12.69 4.103e+07 5.642e+07
```

Comment: by saying bilinear, i meant two lines intersecting mathematically consistent point. So i got it slope 1 and 2 are fine. my problem is intersection point. What i understand is intercept2 is the intersecting point Y coordinate. what about the end point X ot Y coordinate, is the maximum X in the array is automatically the end point X coordinate? Sorry i was expecting to get out the equation directly like y=mx+c, but could not come up.Again thank you for the response

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I was poking around myself for information on using segmented, and since I think I understand what you're asking, can offer a quick answer.  The 'x' value at which the two curves meet is the breakpoint.  Using your example:

> linear2

Call: segmented.lm(obj = linear1, seg.Z = ~X, psi = 5e-04, data = d)

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:

(Intercept)            X         U1.X
  2.997e+04    2.212e+09   -2.167e+09

Estimated Break-Point(s) psi1.X : 4.215e-05

The linear equation set for your model is:

y = slope1*x + intercept1 when x <= breakpoint

y = slope2*x + intercept2 when x >  breakpoint